# cURL https://www.instagram.com/{USERNAME}/?__a=1 from production server return the Instagram login page

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

on my local server, I can do a cURL request to this Instagram endpoint: https://www.instagram.com/{USERNAME}/?__a=1
I get JSON data in return.
I specify that I have logged out from Instagram on my local computer.

When I do the same cURL request on my production server, I get the HTML of the Instagram login page in return.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Instagram most probably IP blocked your hosting's IP range, as they blacklist many cloud providers to make it harder to deploy 3rd party services. If possible, route the traffic over your home computer (which you know that can access) and see if it works or not.

Comment: Same problem, in localhost works perfect, but im production not